# Adding hyperlink with text in the ClipBoard

Tags: java, android

I am using ClipBoard as follows to store the url string, however, when I paste it into textview, then it shows as it is, however, I want to add custom text and when user clicks on it, it takes him to the url.

```
ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("Click Here URL", "http://www.youtube.com");
clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
```

As we are adding hyperlink into text, if you click on the url below, it will take you to the youtube.
[Click here](http://www.youtube.com)

Custom clickable links with text, I am wondering how to achieve this functionality.

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("Click Here URL", "<a href=“http://www.youtube.com”>here</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `newHtmlText` instead of `newPlainText`

```
    ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    String url = "<a href=\"http://www.youtube.com\">Click Here URL</a>";
    ClipData clipData = ClipData.newHtmlText("Click Here URL", "Click Here URL",url);
    clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clipData);
```